# Finding $f(x)$ such that $\int_a^x \left( \frac{f(t)-f(a)}{(t-a)^2} - \frac{f'(a)}{t-a}\right) \mathrm{d}t$ has no critical points

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

If $$\int_a^x \left( \dfrac{f(t)-f(a)}{(t-a)^2} -  \dfrac{f'(a)}{t-a}\right) \mathrm{d}t$$ has no critical points, then  $f(x)$ can be:
(A) $x+\sin x$ 
(B) $x^3+3x+2$ 
(C) $x^2+\sin x$
(D) $x^2 - \sin x$

There is a very similar question here: [fIf function $f(x)$ has no critical points, then function $f(x)$ can be](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099808/fif-function-fx-has-no-critical-points-then-function-fx-can-be) but it doesn't have any answers.

---

**My attempt**
Let $$g(x) = \int_a^x \left( \dfrac{f(t)-f(a)}{(t-a)^2} -  \dfrac{f'(a)}{t-a}\right) \mathrm{d}t $$
A critical point is a point in the interior of the domain such that either the derivative of the function at that point is zero or the function is not differentiable at that point.
$$\begin{align} g'(x) &\ = \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2} -  \dfrac{f'(a)}{x-a} \\ &\ = \dfrac{-1}{x-a} \left( f'(a) - \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right)  \end{align}$$
And we know that $f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Using L'Hôpital's rule,
$$ \begin{align} \lim_{x \to a} g'(x) &\ = \lim_{x \to a} \left( \dfrac{f'(x)}{x-a} - \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2} \right) \\ &\ = \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{x-a} \\ &\ = f''(a) \end{align} $$

Now, looking at the options, (A) and (B) are ruled out because $f''(a)=0$ for certain $a$ in both of those options. This leaves (C) and (D) both of whose double derivatives are positive for all $a$. But is this enough to conclude anything? I have only checked in the neighbourhood of $x=a$ and have no information about any other point. How would one complete this solution?